# unable to update - repository is not updated, invalid signatures

Tags: package-management, system-installation

I am unable to update libs and dependencies

```
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.anydesk.com all In Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.anydesk.com/dists/all/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
```

getting the above error help needed, thanks in advance

Comment: the anydesk repositories are signed with an outdated key.  They should have provided an updated key, and if they continue to not provide an updated key for you to add to your system, then you are going to have to contact AnyDesk for support - it's their software repository so it's not really something we can *fix* if they haven't provided an updated key

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to follow their documentation from http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html .

To (re)add GPG key open terminal and execute:

```
wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

then update package lists by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentation in [anydesk/howto.html](http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html) is **outdated** if you are using Debian 12. As you can read in `man 8 apt-key`

> apt-key(8) will last be available in Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22.04

So, I wrote a simple bash script to install anydesk in Debian Bookworm from repository:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -O- https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/anydesk.gpg > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/anydesk.gpg] http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list

apt update && apt -y install anydesk
```

Comment: It is advisable to use /usr/share/keyrings/ instead of /etc/apt/keyrings/ for third party repositories. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty Also the tee commands will need to be run with sudo.